# JDBC Appender log4j2 error

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to log error into PostgreSQL database using log4j2. Though I am able to do that, I have a doubt.

(Case:0) If I try to run the code shown as it is, it doesn't give any error.

(Case:1) But if I uncomment the line 'System.out.println(Utils.hello);' it shows null pointer exception. I think this is mostly because the logger is null in Utils Class. I am initializing it but don't know why this is happening.

I tried debugging this (in case:1) and found out that the logger variable is getting initialized and whenever the control reaches the 'System.out.println(Utils.hello)', it becomes null. I just want to know whats happening here (not solution for how to log to DB).  Whats actually happening inside for the above 2 cases and why 'case:1' is giving error. Thanks in advance. :-)

Main function:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    System.out.println("aa");
    System.out.println(Utils.class);
    //System.out.println(Utils.hello);
    if (args.length == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        Processing procObj = new Processing();      
    }
}
```

Utils Class:

```
public class Utils {

public static Properties prop;
static InputStream input;
public static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger= LogManager.getLogger(Utils.class);
public static int hello = 10;

public static void initProperties() {
    System.out.println(logger);
    logger.traceEntry();
    prop = new Properties();
    input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(prop.getClass().getResource("/config.properties").getPath());
        prop.load(input);
        logger.info("Successully completed initialization process.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("{} Error initializing from properties file. <{}>",Utils.prop.getProperty("utility"), e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("{} Error initializing from properties file. <{}>",Utils.prop.getProperty("utility"), e);
    }
}
}
```

ConnectionFactory Class:

```
  public class ConnectionFactory  implements ConnectionSource{
 private static interface Singleton {
  final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
 }

 private final DataSource dataSource;

 public ConnectionFactory() {
     Utils.initProperties();
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("user", "user");
  properties.setProperty("password", "password");

  GenericObjectPool pool = new GenericObjectPool();

  DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
   "url", properties);
  new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null,
    "SELECT 1", 3, false, false,
    Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

  this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
 }

 public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
  return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
 }

@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
}
}
```

Processing Class:

```
public class Processing {
    String query;
    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Processing.class);

    public Processing() {
        Utils.initProperties();
        ....
    }
    .....
    .....
    }
```

The error is:

```
  2017-06-09 16:38:32,318 main ERROR JdbcDatabaseManager JdbcManager{name=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, tableName=error, columnConfigs=[{ name=key, layout=null, literal=-100, timestamp=false }, { name=create_date, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=create_user, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=error_message, layout=%msg, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]} Could not perform database startup operations: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to obtain connection from factory method. java.sql.SQLException: Failed to obtain connection from factory method.
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:54)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.startupInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:74)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.startup(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.start(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:260)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
    at mypackage.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:19)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at mypackage.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at mypackage.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:40)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mypackage.Utils.initProperties(Utils.java:45)
    at mypackage.ConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionFactory.java:23)
    at mypackage.ConnectionFactory$Singleton.<clinit>(ConnectionFactory.java:17)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using very complex logic and probably wrong logic for initializing `Logger` and due this this logic, you are getting such error.

Following things are happening behind the scene when you uncomment `System.out.println(Utils.hello);` line -

1. `main()` method execution starts.
2. Now, when execution come to `System.out.println(Utils.hello);` line, `Java class loader` tries to load `Utils class` for accessing `hello static variable`.
3. During the loading of `Utils class`, all `static variables` are initialized including `logger variable`.
4. Now, since, you are using `JDBC appender` for `log4j2` configuration, `LogManager` tries to get database connection by calling `ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection()` method.
5. In your `ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection()` method call, constructor of this singleton class is called.
6. In constructor body, you are calling `Utils.initProperties()` method.
7. In `Utils.initProperties()` method, you are using `logger static variable` but, in actual, your `logger static variable` is still not initialized and due to this, you got `NullPointerException` when you use `logger` in this method.

Now, to solve this issue, you should change your logic to break this chain. One solution is not to use `Logger` in `Utils class`. However, still, you need check other possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Shouldn't it be the same case when 'Processing' class object is getting instantiated? Cause, in the 'Processing' class constructor, I am calling 'Utils.initProperties()' method.

Comment: Probably no because before instantiating `Processing class`, your `static logger` variable will get initialized. During the initialization of `logger` variable, complete database connection logic will get executed. So, when the constructor of `Processing` class will start executing, `jdbc appender` is properly initialized so calling `Utils.initProperties();` method will not create this exception

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. When the 'Processing' class constructor is called, it will try to initialize the static 'logger' variable which in turn will call 'Utils.initProperties()' in 'ConnectionFactory' class. So now, 'Utils' class static members will be initialized that includes static 'logger' variable of 'Utils' class. Won't the initialization of static 'logger' variable in 'Utils' class results in a call to 'Utils.initProperties()' (call happening in 'ConnectionFactory' class) forming a loop?